# What does max_user_connections mean?

Tags: php

What does max_user_connections mean?

My teacher said it's the max_user_connections settings limits the number of database connections on a per user basis.It sets a limit on the maximum number of simultaneous connections any individual user may have to your MySQL database.

As I understand that means if max_user_connections is 10, when there are 20 IPs connect to my database at the same time, it'd be fine. It will display error only when there is one IP that tried to make more than 10 connections at the same time. But I'm not so sure about this.

Comment: It is related not to IP, but to MySQL account. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections  `The maximum number of simultaneous connections permitted to any given MySQL user account` So, those 20 simultaneous connections will not be able to use the same account.

Answer (score 1):

This limits the number of simultaneous connections that can be made by any given account, but places no limits on what a client can do once connected. 
From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html